# SQL Server Stored Procedure Merge Command Gives Invalid Object Name Message

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, merge

I am writing a stored procedure that merges two tables with identical schema from two databases. I searched for an answer and thought it might be a permission issue, but I cannot resolve the problem.

Here is the error message:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spMergeDefects, Line 66
>   Invalid object name

Here is the stored procedure code:

```
DECLARE @MergeOutput TABLE
(
ActionType  nvarchar(10),
del_guidDefectID    uniqueidentifier,
del_idintDefectID   int,
del_fkintStructureID    int,
del_fkintDefectTypeID   int,
del_tinSeverityCode tinyint,
del_intCreatedBy    int,
del_dtmDateInspected    datetime,
del_bitRepaired bit,
del_dtmRepaired datetime,
del_intRepairedBy   int,
del_tintDefectStatus    tinyint,
del_strRepairWorkOrder  varchar(20),
del_bitTempRepaired bit,
del_dtmTempRepaired datetime,
del_intModifiedBy   int,
del_dtmModified datetime,   
del_bitCircuitSpecific  bit,
del_strCircuit  varchar(20),
del_strUser1    varchar(50),
del_strUser2    varchar(50),
del_intNADefectLodID    int,
del_fkstrInspectionCycleID  varchar(10),
del_strNote varchar(255),
del_SpanDirection   varchar(10),
del_Distance    int,
del_Deleted bit,
ins_guidDefectID    uniqueidentifier,
ins_idintDefectID   int,
ins_fkintStructureID    int,
ins_fkintDefectTypeID   int,
ins_tinSeverityCode tinyint,
ins_intCreatedBy    int,
ins_dtmDateInspected    datetime,
ins_bitRepaired bit,
ins_dtmRepaired datetime,
ins_intRepairedBy   int,
ins_tintDefectStatus    tinyint,
ins_strRepairWorkOrder  varchar(20),
ins_bitTempRepaired bit,
ins_dtmTempRepaired datetime,
ins_intModifiedBy   int,
ins_dtmModified datetime,   
ins_bitCircuitSpecific  bit,
ins_strCircuit  varchar(20),
ins_strUser1    varchar(50),
ins_strUser2    varchar(50),
ins_intNADefectLodID    int,
ins_fkstrInspectionCycleID  varchar(10),
ins_strNote varchar(255),
ins_SpanDirection   varchar(10),
ins_Distance    int,
ins_Deleted bit
```

);

```
MERGE [tblMM-Defects] AS tgt
USING dbo.NGFIElecMobile.[tblMM-Defects] AS src
ON tgt.guidDefectID = src.guidDefectID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
    tgt.fkintStructureID = src.fkintStructureID,
    tgt.fkintDefectTypeID = src.fkintDefectTypeID,
    tgt.tinSeverityCode = src.tinSeverityCode,
    tgt.intCreatedBy = src.intCreatedBy,
    tgt.dtmDateInspected = src.dtmDateInspected,
    tgt.bitRepaired = src.bitRepaired,
    tgt.dtmRepaired = src.dtmRepaired,
    tgt.intRepairedBy = src.intRepairedBy,
    tgt.tintDefectStatus = src.tintDefectStatus,
    tgt.strRepairWorkOrder = src.strRepairWorkOrder,
    tgt.bitTempRepaired = src.bitTempRepaired,
    tgt.intModifiedBy = src.intModifiedBy,
    tgt.dtmModified = src.dtmModified,
    tgt.bitCircuitSpecific = src.bitCircuitSpecific,
    tgt.strCircuit = src.strCircuit,
    tgt.strUser1 = src.strUser1,
    tgt.strUser2 = src.strUser2,
    tgt.fkstrInspectionCycleID = src.fkstrInspectionCycleID,
    tgt.strNote = src.strNote,
    tgt.SpanDirection = src.SpanDirection,
    tgt.Distance = src.Distance

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT 
    (fkintStructureID,
    fkintDefectTypeID,
    tinSeverityCode,
    intCreatedBy,
    dtmDateInspected,
    bitRepaired,
    dtmRepaired,
    intRepairedBy,
    tintDefectStatus,
    strRepairWorkOrder,
    bitTempRepaired,
    intModifiedBy,
    dtmModified,
    bitCircuitSpecific,
    strCircuit,
    strUser1,
    strUser2,
    fkstrInspectionCycleID,
    strNote,
    SpanDirection,
    Distance)

    VALUES
    (src.fkintStructureID,
    src.fkintDefectTypeID,
    src.tinSeverityCode,
    src.intCreatedBy,
    src.dtmDateInspected,
    src.bitRepaired,
    src.dtmRepaired,
    src.intRepairedBy,
    src.tintDefectStatus,
    src.strRepairWorkOrder,
    src.bitTempRepaired,
    src.intModifiedBy,
    src.dtmModified,
    src.bitCircuitSpecific,
    src.strCircuit,
    src.strUser1,
    src.strUser2,
    src.fkstrInspectionCycleID,
    src.strNote,
    src.SpanDirection,
    src.Distance
    )

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
        AND tgt.CheckedOutForInsp = 1 AND CheckOutID = @CheckOutID THEN
    DELETE

    OUTPUT
    $action,
    DELETED.guidDefectID,       
    DELETED.idDefectID, 
    DELETED.fkStructureID,
    DELETED.fkDefectTypeID,     
    DELETED.tinSeverityCode,        
    DELETED.CreatedBy,
    DELETED.dtmDateInspected,
    DELETED.bitRepaired,
    DELETED.dtmRepaired,    
    DELETED.RepairedBy, 
    DELETED.tDefectStatus,
    DELETED.strRepairWorkOrder,
    DELETED.bitTempRepaired,    
    DELETED.dtmTempRepaired,    
    DELETED.ModifiedBy,
    DELETED.dtmModified,        
    DELETED.bitCircuitSpecific,
    DELETED.strCircuit,
    DELETED.strUser1,
    DELETED.strUser2,
    DELETED.NADefectLodID,
    DELETED.fkstrInspectionCycleID,
    DELETED.strNote,    
    DELETED.SpanDirection,
    DELETED.Distance,
    DELETED.[Deleted],
    INSERTED.guidDefectID,      
    INSERTED.idDefectID,    
    INSERTED.fkStructureID,
    INSERTED.fkDefectTypeID,        
    INSERTED.tinSeverityCode,       
    INSERTED.CreatedBy,
    INSERTED.dtmDateInspected,
    INSERTED.bitRepaired,
    INSERTED.dtmRepaired,   
    INSERTED.RepairedBy,    
    INSERTED.tDefectStatus,
    INSERTED.strRepairWorkOrder,
    INSERTED.bitTempRepaired,   
    INSERTED.dtmTempRepaired,   
    INSERTED.ModifiedBy,
    INSERTED.dtmModified,       
    INSERTED.bitCircuitSpecific,
    INSERTED.strCircuit,
    INSERTED.strUser1,
    INSERTED.strUser2,
    INSERTED.NADefectLodID,
    INSERTED.fkstrInspectionCycleID,
    INSERTED.strNote,   
    INSERTED.SpanDirection,
    INSERTED.Distance,
    INSERTED.[Deleted]
    INTO @MergeOutput
    ;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `dbo.NGFIElecMobile.[tblMM-Defects]` seems odd for three-part naming in `database.schema.table` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your `USING dbo.NGFIElecMobile.[tblMM-Defects] AS src` line should really be `USING NGFIElecMobile.dbo.[tblMM-Defects] AS src`

There may be other problems after that.

Here is some guidance for proper multipart naming in T-SQL:
[Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx)